# elasticsearch regroup aggs by prefix

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica

Hi i make a search facets with elasticsearch so i use aggs to get this facets but i would like to regroup all term start with text until the first '/'

Example some value are indexing like 'levelone/leveltwo'
but i would like to regroup all same levelone value

i try that but it does not work

```
  'aggs' = array( 'tags => array ('terms' => array (
                                  'field' => $filter,
                                   'size' => 0,
                                   'include' =>  ".*/.*",
                    )
               ) 
         )
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you give an example with some documents and the desired output?

Comment: edit is it more clear ?